# How to run dissect in J?

Tags: j

I have J9.02 installed in Debian-based OS. I try to run `dissect` but it fails:

```
   load 'debug/dissect'
   dissect '10 + i. 3 3'
value error
|value error: wd
|       wd DISSECT

|value error: wd
|       wd'timer 0'
```

Any hints how to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Console or qt? `dissect` does not work on console version

Comment: indeed, I run it through console. I bet I need to rely on https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Guides/Compiling_Jqt/Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dissect requires a gui front end. You need to run it from Jqt and it sounds like you are in jconsole.